# Form keeps redirecting before submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built this function, that executes when a user clicks a button; it inserts a list, and 2 button elements, into an ordered list wrapped in a form. however whenever i click the spawn button, it momentarily spawns the new elements, and then instantly redirects to the action/processing php page of the form, which redirects back to the previous page due to fields not being filled etc. I have not pressed submit, so I am confused as to why its processing the form?

here is my JS function:

```js
function spawnSilly() //spawn chapters function
        {

            var div = document.createElement("LI"); //creating elements
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var del_button = document.createElement("BUTTON")
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");     //setting attributes
            input.setAttribute("name", "chapterInput" + stringNumber);
            input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Title");
            input.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.setAttribute("type", "button");
            button.setAttribute("onClick", "redirect()");
            button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            button.innerHTML = "Edit";
            div.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.setAttribute("id", "var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();")
            del_button.innerHTML = "Delete Chapter";
            del_button.setAttribute("onClick", "removeElement(this.id)")
            div.appendChild(input)      //appending to list
            div.appendChild(button)
            div.appendChild(del_button);
            var chapterNumber = getCount(document.getElementById('spawnList'), false) //setting number of chapter
            var number = $('#spawnList').children(); //fetching number of children in list
            var stringNumber = String(number) //setting chapter number to string for name attribute in input
            var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
            list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[number]); //inserting one after another
            var newChapterNumber = chapterNumber + 1;  //setting elements class as their chapter number
            input.setAttribute("class", newChapterNumber);
            button.setAttribute("class", newChapterNumber);
            div.setAttribute("class", newChapterNumber);
            del_button.setAttribute("class", newChapterNumber);
            input.setAttribute("index", newChapterNumber);
            button.setAttribute("index", newChapterNumber);
            div.setAttribute("index", newChapterNumber);
            del_button.setAttribute("index", newChapterNumber);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="title-processing.php" method="post">
    <ol id="spawnList">


    </ol>
    <button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add Chapter</button>
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be so great! :)

Comment: Why are you setting `id` to a string which contains javascript expression `var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();`

Comment: to give each spawned group a unique id :)

Comment: check what happens after removing type="submit" from 2nd button...

Comment: Khan - it still redirects to the processing page sadly

Comment: It would, the 2nd button has no control over the first button

Comment: freedom - I have a spawned delete button that deletes anything with the id of the spawned list item, if what you say is true, and i spawned 5 list elements, they would all get deleted if i pressed any delete button, however only the group of elements the button spawned with gets deleted, meaning each spawned group has a unique id.

Comment: akem - not really relevant to the question - would be better if you'd provided a [mcve] - with the *minimal* part not including any of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `type=` for a button is `submit` - so by omitting `type=` the system adds `type=submit`, so your button:

```
<button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add Chapter</button>
```

is actually

```
<button type='submit' id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add Chapter</button>
```

specify the type explicitly to stop your form being submitted:

```
<button type='button' id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly();">Add Chapter</button>
```

Comment: Ahh... that is exactly which I could not recall... My mind was telling me there is something to be done with type attribute... :P